# Ruby on Rails Localhost routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I am following [this tutorial](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails.html?page=2). All is going well until I try create a controller and view it in my browser.

The server is running and it shows the default page okay (`http://127.0.0.1:3000`).

I ran `ruby script\generate controller MyTest` in my command line and it generated the correct folders and files.

The problem is, when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/My_Test/` it says:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue
>   and we'll take a look at it shortly.

This must be something I have overlooked somewhere. Any help is appreciated!

ruby  1.8.6

rails 2.3.4

Just checked my development logs. Here is what it says:

> /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Sep 24 02:21:04
>   +0100 2009   Status: 500 Internal Server Error   no such file to load --
>   sqlite3
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in
>   `require'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`
>   new_constants_in'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in
>   `require'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in`
>   require_library_or_gem'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in
>   `silence_warnings'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in`
>   require_library_or_gem'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:10:in
>   `sqlite3_connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in`
>   send'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in
>   `new_connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in`
>   checkout_new_connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in
>   `checkout'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in`
>   loop'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in
>   `checkout'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`
>   synchronize'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in
>   `checkout'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in`
>   connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in
>   `connection'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in`
>   cache'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in`
>   call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in`
>   call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`
>   call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in
>   `synchronize'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`
>   call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in`
>   run'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in`
>   call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in`
>   each'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in
>   `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:46:in`
>   service'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in
>   `service'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`
>   run'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in
>   `start_thread'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`
>   start'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in
>   `start_thread'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`
>   start'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in
>   `each'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`
>   start'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in
>   `start'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`
>   start'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in
>   `run'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:111
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>       C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'
>       script/server:3

I have no idea what this means but one thing I noticed is that it says sqlite3 - I am not using that (I am using MySql). Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old tutorial, many things have changed since then.

You can check [this](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails/) instead.

Comment: While the other answers were correct and did help, I had to mark this as the right answer because doing a different tutorial just seems to be the best thing to do. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your log file to actually see what went wrong. You will find it in the log directory in the root of your rails application.

However, given that you are running development mode you should had seen a more verbose error message (with a stack trace and session information) so it's most likely an error in your rails setup such as a misconfigured database.yml file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added my development log to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your config/database.yml to use your mysql database instead of sqlite.

When you start a new Rails project you can specify which database you want to use with:

> rails -d mysql

Comment: Just did this but I am getting an error message to do with LIBMYSQL.dll

Comment: The mysql dll cannot be found. You can try to set the path of your libmysql.dll in your system path or copy it to your ruby\bin directory.

Comment: gem install mysql
newer versions of rails don't come with the mysql gem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed sqlite3? Rails by default uses sqlite3 database and it throws this error when it is unable to find it.

Try "ruby gem install sqlite3" command.